# Why is my program generating random results when I nest it?

Tags: c, gcc, parallel-processing, nested, openmp

I made this parallel matrix multiplication program using nesting of for loops in OpenMP. When I run the program the displays the answer randomly ( mostly ) with varying indice of the resultant matrix. Here is the snippet of the code :

```
#pragma omp parallel for

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        C[i][j]=0; 
        #pragma omp parallel for
            for(m=0;m<N;m++){
                C[i][j]=A[i][m]*B[m][j]+C[i][j];
            }
        printf("C:i=%d j=%d %f \n",i,j,C[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Matrix multiplication can't be parallelized this way.  You're seeing race conditions playing out differently.

Comment: Looks like a classic race condition.

Answer (score 1):

These are the symptoms of a so called "race conditions" as the commenters already stated.

The threads OpenMP uses are independent of each other but the results of the individual loops of the matrix multiplication are not, so one thread might be at a different position than the other one and suddenly you are in trouble if you depend on the order of the results.

You can only parallelize the outmost loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int n;
  double **A, **B, **C, **D, t;
  int i, j, k;
  struct timeval start, stop;

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s a positive integer >= 2 and < 1 mio\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  n = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (n <= 2 || n >= 1000000) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s a positive integer >= 2 and < 1 mio\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // make it repeatable
  srand(0xdeadbeef);

  // allocate memory for and initialize A
  A = malloc(sizeof(*A) * n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    A[i] = malloc(sizeof(**A) * n);
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      A[i][j] = (double) ((rand() % 100) / 99.);
    }
  }
  // do the same for B
  B = malloc(sizeof(*B) * n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    B[i] = malloc(sizeof(**B) * n);
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      B[i][j] = (double) ((rand() % 100) / 99.);
    }
  }

  // and C but initialize with zero
  C = malloc(sizeof(*C) * n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    C[i] = malloc(sizeof(**C) * n);
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      C[i][j] = 0.0;
    }
  }

  // ditto with D
  D = malloc(sizeof(*D) * n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    D[i] = malloc(sizeof(**D) * n);
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      D[i][j] = 0.0;
    }
  }

  // some coarse timing
  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
  // naive matrix multiplication
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];
      }
    }
  }
  gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
  t = ((stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000u +
       stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1.e6;
  printf("Timing for naive run    = %.10g\n", t);

  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
#pragma omp parallel shared(A, B, C) private(i, j, k)
#pragma omp for
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        D[i][j] = D[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];
      }
    }
  }
  gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
  t = ((stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000u +
       stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1.e6;
  printf("Timing for parallel run = %.10g\n", t);

  // check result
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if (D[i][j] != C[i][j]) {
        printf("Cell %d,%d differs with delta(D_ij-C_ij) = %.20g\n", i, j,
               D[i][j] - C[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }

  // clean up
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    free(A[i]);
    free(B[i]);
    free(C[i]);
    free(D[i]);
  }
  free(A);
  free(B);
  free(C);
  free(D);

  puts("All ok? Bye");

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

(`n>2000` might need some patience to get the result)

But it's not fully true. You could (but shouldn't) try to get the innermost loop with something like

```
sum = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
   sum +=  A[i][k] * B[k][j];
}
D[i][j] = sum;
```

Does not seem to be faster, is even slower with small `n`.
With the original code and `n = 2500` (only one run):

```
Timing for naive run    = 124.466307
Timing for parallel run = 44.154538
```

About the same with the reduction:

```
Timing for naive run    = 119.586365
Timing for parallel run = 43.288371
```

With a smaller `n = 500`

```
Timing for naive run    = 0.444061
Timing for parallel run = 0.150842
```

It is already slower with reduction at that size:

```
Timing for naive run    = 0.447894
Timing for parallel run = 0.245481
```

It might win for *very* large `n` but I lack the necessary patience.
Nevertheless, a last one with `n = 4000` (OpenMP part only):

Normal:

```
Timing for parallel run = 174.647404
```

With reduction:

```
Timing for parallel run = 179.062463
```

That difference is still fully inside the error-bars.

A better way to multiply large matrices (at ca. `n>100` ) would be the Schönhage-Straßen algorithm.

Oh: I just used square matrices for convenience not because they must be of that form! But if you have rectangular matrices with a large length-ratio you might try to change the way the loops run; column-first or row-first can make a significant difference here.